# Ubuntu 14.04LTS hangs when i change brightness of my display on Dell N5010 laptop

Tags: dell, laptop, brightness, inspiron, backlight

I have dell n5010

my system hang when I try to change brightness of the display and this happen only when my system on battery

please help how to solve this problem

Comment: @bain
Thank you so much that solution worked like a charm for me

Comment: @ArYaNsH If the answer helped please mark it as "useful" by clicking the up arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the update of Ubuntu 16.04, the problem of brightness solved.

Answer (score 0):

The Dell Inspiron N5010 (and other Dell laptops eg. Dell Studio 1558, Inspiron 1464, Inspiron 1564, Inspiron M5010) has a bug in the firmware that causes it to hang in the backlight code under certain scenarios. This is [kernel.org bug #57571 - Dell Inspiron N5010: freeze on adjusting brightness unless acpi_backlight=vendor is specified on boot](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57571)  and [Launchpad bug #1007765 - brightness adjusting crashes system](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1007765). There are two workarounds that may help:

- Create the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with contents:

  ```
  Section "Device"
      Identifier  "card0"
      Driver      "intel"
      Option      "Backlight"    "intel_backlight"
      BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
  EndSection
  ```

  Log out and log back in again then test.
- Add `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the boot parameters (some users report that this does not work for them)

Comment: Doesn't work for me (Ubuntu 13.10)

Comment: @mac Please report it on the kernel.org bug report #57571. I have not followed the bug closely, so I do not know why it was closed as "DOCUMENTED" instead of a having a bios quirks fix. IMHO the kernel should not expose a buggy interface that, when used, results in a system hang. (Also, I do not see where this problem was actually documented...)

Comment: I had the same problem with my Inspiron 14R 850 using Ubuntu 16.04. The boot parameter did not resolve, but creating the 20-intel.conf file worked like a charm! Upvoting!

Comment: I tried the first method on Ubuntu 20.04 and I DO NOT recommend it. After adding the file I logged out, when I tried to log back in it just reloaded the login screen. So I rebooted the system and it gave me a blank screen. I tried several things to fix this, and if nothing worked i considered reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch. Finally I went to the terminal in recovery mode and and deleted this file. After rebooting the system everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

For people that stumbled upon this years later (like me). Neither of these approaches worked for me. Probably because I have an AMD/ATI graphics card which is using the `radeon_bl0` interface.

What fixed it for me was adding

```
echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog
```

to

```
/etc/rc.local
```

A longer explanation to this workaround can be found here
[Comment 96 for bug 1007765](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1007765/comments/96)